# Using Data to create a statistics leaderboard from an API

Tags: api

I'm trying to use data from an API called "SpeedAPI" from the following link:

http://world.needforspeed.com/SpeedAPI/doc/

My goal is to use the player statistics and data to create a leaderboard for the racing track times. This API comes from a racing game in which players try to compete for the best times on tracks. My goal is to have the website with the data I requested from the API show player profiles, their event times, etc. However, I do not understand how to "get" the data from the API. I have looked through the example, but I'm confused on how to "get" the data.

I'm also curious as to what coding language I'll need to code this data in. PHP, Python, etc.? If anyone can help me with anything above, please reply back. This has had me stuck for months now researching all over Google.

Thank you.